# Serialize instance for Data.Text?

Tags: haskell, serialization

I need to serialize a data type to disk that uses `Data.Text`, here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Serialize (Serialize)
import Data.Text (Text)
import GHC.Generics

data Foo = Foo Text deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord, Generic)
instance Serialize Foo
-- instance Serialize Text
```

As written, this generates the error:

```
No instance for (Serialize Text)
  arising from a use of `Data.Serialize.$gdmput'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Serialize Text)
In the expression: (Data.Serialize.$gdmput)
In an equation for `put': put = (Data.Serialize.$gdmput)
In the instance declaration for `Serialize Foo'
```

If I uncomment the `instance Serialize Text` line, then this more cryptic error comes about:

```
No instance for (Data.Serialize.GSerialize (Rep Text))
  arising from a use of `Data.Serialize.$gdmput'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (Data.Serialize.GSerialize (Rep Text))
In the expression: (Data.Serialize.$gdmput)
In an equation for `put': put = (Data.Serialize.$gdmput)
In the instance declaration for `Serialize Text'
```

I could implement the `Serialize` instance manually, but this seems like a situation where orphaned instances would be a real problem, and furthermore, I don't think I know enough about `Data.Text` to serialize / deserialize it quickly and correctly.

Is there a standard solution to this problem? (I'm also not wedded to using cereal's Serialize instance, but I have been having some version issues relating to using the binary package; binary-0.5.1.1 doesn't seem to support Generics well, and I'd like to avoid writing boilerplate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the missing instance should be considered a feature: `Data.Text` talks about text, which should be kept distinct from its representation. So the canonical way to approach the problem is to encode the `Data.Text` to a `Data.ByteString` in the encoding you want it to be (or, better, some specification or metadata wants it to be), and then serialize the `Data.ByteString`.

The most common encoding functions can be found in [Data.Text.Encoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html).

Comment: Thanks! I wrote an instance in terms of encodeUtf8 & decodeUtf8; that seems to be working, although I'm running into issues with more complex types that contain Text.  I think those issues are due to misunderstandings I have about Serialize.  When I have it all resolved I'll post the instance I'm using here for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the instance I ended up using, based on Joachim Britner's advice:

```
instance Serialize Text where
  put txt = put $ encodeUtf8 txt
  get     = fmap decodeUtf8 get
```

As pointed out, you may need different encode / decode functions, but the structure should be the same.

Comment: That looks right. That is the approach taken by SafeCopy library, which does provide an instance for Text. I was initially confused by your question because I was serializing Text already but I am using SafeCopy.http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy-0.8.2/docs/src/Data-SafeCopy-Instances.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to address this issue, I just published [`cereal-text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-text) on Hackage.

The implementation is similar to [rcreswick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385135/2597135), however `cereal-text` also provides an instance for lazy text.

Install the library using `cabal install cereal-text` and import the instances using:

```haskell
import Data.Serialize.Text ()
```

Note that for some applications [`safecopy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy) is not usable, because it depends on Template Haskell which is not available on all platforms.